# Is there a "pattern" or a group that defines *rc files in *nix environments?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm starting to use command line a little more, and I see there are a lot of ways to configure some config files in my `$HOME`. This is good, since you can customize it the way you really like.

Unfortunately, for begginners, having too many options is a little confusing. For example, I created `.bash_alias` for some alias I'm using. I didn't even know this option existed, I'm used to simply edit .bashrc.

Do exist a pattern, a "good practice", envisioning **flexibility** and **modularity** in terms of rc files structure? Do exist a standardization group for this, or every body just creates it's own configuration setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the configuration files are all dependent upon the software that uses them. in most cases, the file is named `.<programname>rc` in some cases it's a config file in a 'hidden' `.` directory, i.e. `~/.fluxbox/init`

there is nothing wrong with putting your aliases in the `.bashrc` file, `.bash_alias` is another shell script called from within `.bashrc`, some people just like to segregate their configurations while others, like me, prefer putting all our related configurations in the same file, for easy management.

in my `.bashrc` there is:

```
#if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
#    . ~/.bash_aliases
#fi
```

which is what i presume is in yours, only not commented out, meaning it checks that `.bash_alias` is a file, and then 'sources' it into the `.bashrc` file (that's what `. ~/.bash_alias` means, `.` in this case is a shortcut for `source`)